# Which memory cache optimal for social network?

Tags: memcached

We wrote a social network which expected huge amount of users, and we need memory cache for it. In our social network we are using Windows and Linux servers combination. Memory has to be installed on Linux computer.

If you have an experience with memory cache, which is the best choice for this kind of tasks?

What do you think about RADIS, MongoDB, Hibernate or Memcache?

Comment: *"We wrote a social network which expected huge amount of users"* ...  are you sure you're not under an NDA?

Comment: How many are "huge amounts"? What has hibernate to do with caching? Caching what? Caching proxy? I smell the next facebook.

Comment: How are you using a combination of windows and linux servers?

Comment: Theoretically it can be so many users how many it is in facebook. In any case our system should work well for this kind of load.

We have a two applications one is a website, which was written on C# and use IIS as server computer another one is, chat application which use nodejs as server and located on Linux computer.

We need some external memory storage to exchange information between those two applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis/) is a good comparision of NoSQL DBs